# Publish an existent branch from Perforce repository on Helix TeamHub / GitHub / Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, perforce

Despite the fact that Perforce has a lot of FAQs and other tutorial stuff, I am still didn't find a short answer on the next questions:

1. How to publish some of my current p4d(p4s) branches at any of public Git services like Helix TeamHub / GitHub / Bitbucket
2. How to maintain these branches synchronized in both directions.

I understand that I can do it manually simply adding one branch to p4s and Git simultaneously, but I assume that there are tools helping developers to perform this automatically.

The Perforce documentation refers to `git p4`, `Git Connector`, `Git Fusion`, `Helix4Git` tools. But, actually, I am confused by this list of tools, because of still don't understand how it can help me to solve my problem.

Note: I have my P4 Server installed on Windows.